# SparkR read.df ignores delimiter argument

Tags: hadoop, sparkr

I'm running SparkR on an EMR cluster (release emr-5.3.0) and trying to import JSON data from zipped S3 files.

read.df works fine when I'm reading JSON that has a newline as the file delimiter

```
read.df("s3://.../*.json", "json")
```

but it doesn't work when the data was initially logged with

```
"textinputformat.record.delimiter": '\0'
```

(as I only get the first record from each file in my directory).

How do I get read.df to recognize the null character as the record delimiter and parse the entire file and not just the first JSON record then silently fail at the embedded nul?